# PlaySound only plays default "SystemAsterisk" sound (Windows 10, C++, Python)

Tags: python, c++, audio, windows-10, playsound

I'm trying to use Windows' PlaySound function as mentioned here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd743680(v=vs.85).aspx

However, nothing I try can change it from playing the default sound "SystemAsterisk."

I've tried using both C++ and Python and get the same results:

C++:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include <playsoundapi.h>

int main()
{
    PlaySound(TEXT("SystemWelcome"), NULL, SND_ALIAS);
    PlaySound(TEXT("C:\Users\Me\Downloads\sound1.wav"), NULL, SND_FILENAME);
    return 0;
}
```

Both attempts above to play a different sound still return the default Asterisk sound.

Python:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import winsound

winsound.PlaySound("c:/Users/Me/Downloads/sound1.wav", winsound.SYN_ASYNC|winsound.SYN_FILENAME)
```

Again, I get the same results.

Any ideas on what's going on? Perhaps this is a Windows 10 problem?

Comment: In your c++ version you need to escape your backslashes:`C:\\Users\\Me\\Downloads\\sound1.wav`

Comment: The problem with the Python code might be the SYN_ASYNC flag.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me in Windows 7 and in Windows 10:

```
#undef UNICODE
#define UNICODE
#include <windows.h>

#include <stdlib.h>

auto main()
    -> int
{
    bool const ok = !!PlaySound( L"c:/windows/media/ringout.wav", 0, SND_ALIAS );
    return (ok? EXIT_SUCCESS : EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

---

One direct problem with your C++ code is the string literal

```
"C:\Users\Me\Downloads\sound1.wav"
```

where each `\` starts an invalid escape sequence. One simple fix is to use forward slashes, `/`, instead of `\` backslashes.

One possible problem with your Python code is the `SYN_ASYNC` flag. This may cause the function to return immediately. And if the script then exits immediately, you may not necessarily hear any sound.

---

In other news:

- `#include "stdafx.h"` is a non-standard header, and prevents some readers from directly trying your code (they don't have that generated header).
- `TEXT` is obsolete, use Unicode in modern Windows.
- `return 0;` is unnecessary for `main`, it's the default.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried escaping my backslashes. No luck there. Thanks for the additional help with the `#include "stdafx.h"` and `return 0` info. I was just using the standard setup in Visual Studio (a little rusty with C++).

Comment: I tried your code, also had no luck. Also, should I not be including `#include stdafx.h` in my code on StackOverflow? Of course it's only for those using Visual Studio.

Comment: UPDATE: Okay I got yours to work with the `ringout.wav` file. I'll play around with this and try to get my own files working. Thanks!

Comment: FINAL UPDATE: Okay I got my files to work using your code. My .wav files specifically were not working. I used Audacity to convert them to 16 bit PCM and then they started working as well. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Tip: You can mark this answer as "solution" and get some rep points.

Answer (score 1):

Just putting it out there for new python users. 
I was facing the same issue when I ran the script using IDE(VS Code to be specific). 
However, If I used command prompt to run the script using "python script.py", the correct file was played.
Weird.